# Keras LSTM with Variable Sentences Length -- the list of Numpy arrays passing to model not size model expected

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have successfully implemented an LSTM tutorial for generating music. However, I"m struggling to create one for language (my main interest). I have a word index and here are two sample sentences from my data.

sample predictors:

```
[[1],
 [1, 6],
 [1, 6, 241],
 [1, 6, 241, 252],
 [1, 6, 241, 252, 11],
 [1, 6, 241, 252, 11, 59],
 [1, 6, 241, 252, 11, 59, 2],
 [1, 6, 241, 252, 11, 59, 2, 62],
 [1, 6, 241, 252, 11, 59, 2, 62, 663],
 [1, 6, 241, 252, 11, 59, 2, 62, 663, 41],
 [1],
 [1, 3],
 [1, 3, 216],
 [1, 3, 216, 227],
 [1, 3, 216, 227, 26],
 [1, 3, 216, 227, 26, 30],
 [1, 3, 216, 227, 26, 30, 5]]
```

sample labels:

```
[[6],
[241],
[252],
[11],
[59],
[2],
[62],
[663],
[41],
[1],
[3],
[216],
[227],
[26],
[30],
[5],
[1]]
```

The loss should be computed like this: 
[image]
which I want to minimize.

My code for the LSTM is

```
from keras.models import Model
from keras import layers
from keras import Input

vocabulary_size = len(word_index)
dimensions = 200


text_input = Input(shape=(None,))
embedded = layers.Embedding(vocabulary_size, dimensions)(text_input)
encoded = layers.LSTM(vocabulary_size)(embedded)
output = layers.Dense(vocabulary_size, activation='softmax')(encoded)
model = Model(text_input, output)
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['acc'])
model.summary()
model.fit(x, y, epochs=10, batch_size=1)
```

To accommodate the variable sentence length, I set

- `batch_size = 1` because of the variable sentence length
- `shape` of `Input` to `(None, )`

However, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-95228d843a72> in <module>()
     25               metrics=['acc'])
     26 model.summary()
---> 27 model.fit(x, y, epochs=1, batch_size=1)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
    950             sample_weight=sample_weight,
    951             class_weight=class_weight,
--> 952             batch_size=batch_size)
    953         # Prepare validation data.
    954         do_validation = False

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, check_array_lengths, batch_size)
    749             feed_input_shapes,
    750             check_batch_axis=False,  # Don't enforce the batch size.
--> 751             exception_prefix='input')
    752 
    753         if y is not None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_utils.py in standardize_input_data(data, names, shapes, check_batch_axis, exception_prefix)
    100                 'Expected to see ' + str(len(names)) + ' array(s), '
    101                 'but instead got the following list of ' +
--> 102                 str(len(data)) + ' arrays: ' + str(data)[:200] + '...')
    103         elif len(names) > 1:
    104             raise ValueError(

ValueError: Error when checking model input: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 1 array(s), but instead got the following list of 17 arrays: [array([[1]]), array([[1],
       [6]]), array([[  1],
       [  6],
       [241]]), array([[  1],
       [  6],
       [241],
       [252]]), array([[  1],
       [  6],
       [241],
       [252],
 ...
```

Instead of using a list of lists, I tried converting these to a list of numpy arrays, but that didn't change the errror. This was suggested here: 
[keras list of Numpy arrays not the size model expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51100057/keras-list-of-numpy-arrays-not-the-size-model-expected)

```
x = [np.array(i) for i in x]
y = [np.array(i) for i in y]
```

Why am I getting this error even though I structured the model intentionally to handle varying lengths of arrays?

The error is occurring because of the format of my predictors (x). At least, that's what I believe the error indicates.

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I could be misremembering but I believe you should be doing something like

```
y = y.reshape(-1)
```

to get a flat list of labels that Keras seems to desire here. Also training with batch_size of 1 will hurt your performance. I recommend pre-padding your data with a fixed number of `0`s, setting the `mask=True` in the LSTM and using standard batch sizes

Comment: The error is occurring on the input though I believe.

Comment: What is the input shape of `x`. It should be something like `(samples, timesteps, 1)` for keras. If it is two dimensional you should extend it `x.reshape(x.shape + (1,))`. It looks right in the error though

Comment: The input shape here is variable. I originally tried preprocessing using padding. It was my first time building an LSTM though and my model over-fitted a lot (like 30% accuracy with a 6% validation). So I switched to this method with varying array lengths.  Is pre-processing standard? I'm confused why people in a PhD level class can't agree on what the best method is.

Comment: There are like 58635 lists in my x list

Comment: @StanShunpike You should definitly pre-pad so your gradient can be more consistent with > 1 batches. I suspect it will be difficult to learn otherwise. All you need to do is `mask_zero=True` in the embedding layer and pre-pad the input.

Comment: Super. I'll try it. Thanks! :)